# The monerod add the peer failed

Tags: monerod

I start monerod with '--add-peer 172.18.6.15:18080'.
But when I use the command print_cn, the 172.18.6.15 doesn't list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

print_cn prints the current connections. You want print_pl, which will print the peer list, including the one you selected.

Comment: print_pl shows many peers. If I only want to use the peer which I added, how do I do that?

Comment: --add-exclusive-node IP:PORT